# Httpclient: set http method as string, not use HttpGet, HttpPost, etc

Tags: java, httpclient, http-method

How can I make with httpclient a request with body, but without using the dedicated HttpGet/HttpPost, etc?
I would like something similar to:

```
request=createRequest...
request.setHttpMethod
request.setBody
result=request.execute()
```

I actually have to use a DELETE with body and I would prefer not to extend any httpclient specific method.

Comment: Why don't you just use an `HttpDelete` and use `setEntity` to set the body?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What is wrong with the HC API?